# Highcharts - Hide Navigator Range Lines

Tags: highcharts

How can i hide the horizontal line as well as the vertical range lines in navigator as shown in the image?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `gridLineWidth` to 0:

```
    navigator: {
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 0
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jth4vy9c/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.xAxis.gridLineWidth

Comment: ppotaczek thank you very much for the massive help over the past few days. it's been a mountain to climb this new project i am working on. Do you know how that horizontal line can dissap[ear as well?

Comment: Hi @Christopher Vradis, I am glad that I could help. Do you mean horizontal lines on the main plot? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/goye8d3t/

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek thanks once again. I mean that horizontal line on the upper part of the navigator. (If you see the image on the start of the navigator as i am dragging the handler to the right and i zoom in this grey line appears , as if it is the top border of the navigator).

Comment: Set `navigator.outlineWidth` to 0. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bxdyuc20/

Comment: You are godsent. Thanks